# Javascript passing multiple variables to an object with onclick

Tags: javascript

I am sure this has been asked before, but I am baffled. I am trying to pass multiple variables from a input text to a function that creates a object to then be returned. I have tried multiple things on stack overflow and I am still lost as  to what i need to do.

The question is create a function that asks the user for a monster name, number of health points, and it's primary attack, The function returns an object of this monster type.

The code I have so far is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Input how tall you are in inches and click the button:</p>

Input monsters name: <input id="monsterName" value="" />
<br>
Input health points: <input id="numberOfHealthPoints" value="" />
<br>
Input Primary attack: <input id="primaryAttack" value="" />
<br>
<button onclick="monsterDescription(document.getElementById('monsterName').value, document.getElementById('numberOfHealthPoints').value, document.getElementById('primaryAttack).value)">Calculate Monster</button>

<p id="monster"></p>


<script>

function monsterDescription(name, health, attack)
{
    var monsterType =
    "mN" : name,
    "nOHP": health ,
    "pA" : attack;
    }

    document.getElementById("monster").innerHTML = monsterType;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have got many syntax errors like in `var monsterType = "mN" : name, "nOHP": health, "pA" : attack; }` or `document.getElementById('primaryAttack).value)`. Please, before asking, look into your developer console and find any errors. Then, try to solve it yourself or post the error message here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use *JSON.stringify()* to convert your data into string, And please pay attention with the structure of your JSON Data.**

```
 function monsterDescription(name, health, attack)
 {
     var monsterType =
     {
     "mN" : name,
     "nOHP": health ,
     "pA" : attack
      }

     document.getElementById("monster").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(monsterType);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am new to this and teaching myself, i was just trying everything trying to fix this and just making it worse because I was trying to fix the wrong things.